# How do I compose a string from characters in the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have been trying to reverse a string given as a parameter and I have managed to push to the stack the individual characters via the lower bits of a register (al, bl...). The string I read is ´abcd´, so the memory layout of my stack is the following:

`0xwhatever00` (end line character)

`0xwhatever64` (ascii for d)

`0xwhatever63` (ascii for c)

`0xwhatever62` (ascii for b)

`0xwhatever61` (ascii for a)

Now I would like to compose back the string via pop so that the character´s order is reverted, but I don´t know how. I have tried to create a string variable in nasm `string db 'mystring',0` but I don´t know how to append characters. I have also tried to add the popped value (kind of doesn´t make sense) just for the sake of trying, but I have no clue. Any idea on how to append characters or how to compose strings from characters?

Comment: You write bytes where you want them to be. Where are you putting the result?

Comment: Please show your code so far. But I can tell you right away your idea "via pop so that the character´s order is reverted" will not work right off the bat. You will just get them back in the same order (!). You must *store* them somewhere; for that, no push/pop is necessary.

Comment: push/pop don't make this easier (and use 4x as much memory as working with bytes).  Just use the usual algorithm of pointers to the start/end and walking them inward until they cross in the middle, swapping as you go.

Comment: Passing the string on stack is never correct. Instead, you should pass it's address to the proc. Assuming `EDI` is its address, you then scan and find the end zero and store its address to `ESI`. then you can `DEC ESI` `.loop: CMP EDI, ESI` `JAE .Exit` `MOV AL, [EDI]` `XCHG AL,[ESI]` `MOV [EDI], AL` `INC EDI` `DEC ESI` `JMP .loop`. Note that using `XCHG` is not recommended due to memory lock. `MOV AL, [EDI]` and `INC EDI` can be combined as `STOSB`. You can also optimize it with 'BSWAP' if you can take pain of size checking and branching